# Computing the value of a line integral of a vector field in the plane

Tags: integration, vector-fields, line-integrals, greens-theorem

We are given the vector field $ x^2dx+y^2dy $ and are interested in the line integral of it over the closed equilateral triangle with vertices (0,0) (2,0) (1,-2)

Because the partial derivatives of each piece of this integral is 0, I thought I could use the Fundamental Theorem of Integrals but since it is a closed curve, I don't know if it would be easier to use Green's Theorem or maybe just evaluate each line of the curve separately.

Comment: $\partial(x^2)/\partial y=\partial(y^2)/\partial x=0$, so the integral of a closed curve is $0$, Green's Theorem give exactly this result, it just says something more when $\partial N/\partial x \neq \partial M/ \partial y$.